# How to use JMeter Simple Table Server in Distributed testing?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to get the JMeter Simple Table Server (STS) setup in my distributed tests. Locally, on the master controller, the STS server is started and I am able to read data with the `http://<local IP>:9191/sts/READ...` HTTP request in my Script. As soon as I attempt to run it via my slave using `Remote Start` the test forever hangs. The official documentation is clear in the setup on the master but is no help when it comes to the actual configuration settings needed on the slaves.

The outbound/inbound connections on all machines are allowing port `9191` from all IPs and I have got the plugin installed on both master machine and slaves. The server is started only on the master, the distributed test is then executed using `JMeter GUI > Remote Start`. Both local and public IP in the host of the IP result in the same behaviour.

Normal distributed tests run fine so the connection between machines is not an issue, well it may be an issue on port `9191`, however, as stated previously this port has been opened.

Could anyone who has used this plugin please let me know what setup is required on the Injectors please?

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest checking the following:

1. [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) files on master and slaves for any suspicious entries
2. Introducing timeout for the HTTP Request sampler, by default JMeter doesn't have any timeouts it means that if there is a connectivity issue JMeter will wait for the response from STS **forever** so it worth always having reasonable timeouts, they can be specified under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))
3. Checking the IP address where STS is running using [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command or equivalent as I can think of possible cases:

   - STS is bound to localhost only
   - STS is bound to private address
   - STS is bound to IPv6 address and you're using IPv4 or vi